# Two functions to impose order on queries

Tags: c#, sorting, linq, entity-framework

I am writing a c# program to build generic sort algorithm on a request to a collection of data. The data needs to be sorted based on the supplied columns.I am using Entity framework and Expression builder to achieve the required functionality.

In one of the methods I see that some code is duplicated and I am not getting any idea how I can remove the duplicate code by replacing it with some reusable code.

```
private static IQueryable<T> SortQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, SortFilter sortFilter)
    {
        IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery = null;
        if (sortFilter != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilter.SortOn))
        {
            var sortParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            // Using ; as the delimeter for specifying multiple columns in sort criteria
            string[] sortColumns = sortFilter.SortOn.Split(';');
            foreach (string sortColumn in sortColumns)
            {
                Expression property = NestedExpressionProperty(sortParam, sortColumn);
                orderedQuery = OrderQuery(orderedQuery??query, property, sortParam, sortFilter,ref orderedQuery);
            }
            return orderedQuery;
        }
        else
        {
            var sortParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            Expression property = Expression.Property(sortParam, "Id");
            var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, long>>(
                    property, new[] { sortParam });

            return query.OrderBy(sortExpr);
        }
    }
private static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression property, ParameterExpression sortParam, SortFilter sortFilter, ref IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery)
    {
        if (property.Type == typeof(int))
        {
            var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(property, new[] { sortParam });
            orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending 
                ? (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderBy(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpr)) 
                : (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpr));
        }
        else if (property.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(property, new[] { sortParam });
            orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending 
                ? (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderBy(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpr))
                : (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpr));
        }
        else if (property.Type == typeof(DateTimeOffset?))
        {
            var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTimeOffset>>(
            Expression.Coalesce(property, Expression.Constant(DateTimeOffset.MaxValue)), new[] { sortParam });
            orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending 
                ? (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderBy(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpr))
                : (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpr));
        }
        else
        {
            var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, new[] { sortParam });
            orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending 
                ? (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderBy(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpr))
                : (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpr));
        }
        return orderedQuery;
    }

private static MemberExpression NestedExpressionProperty(Expression expression, string propertyName)
    {
        string[] parts = propertyName.Split('.');
        int partsL = parts.Length;

        return (partsL > 1)
            ?
            Expression.Property(
                NestedExpressionProperty(
                    expression,
                    parts.Take(partsL - 1)
                        .Aggregate((a, i) => a + "." + i)
                ),
                parts[partsL - 1])
            :
            Expression.Property(expression, propertyName);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

These are some general issues I see with your code:

**Repeated Code**

This block of code is repeated 4 times:

```
orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending 
             ? (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderBy(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpr)) 
             : (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpr));
```

Put this into its own function/method and call it instead of copy/pasting it in 4 different places. Something like this (sorry for the pseudo-syntax):

```
setQueryOrderingFromSortFilter(sortFilter, sortExpr, ref orderedQuery)
{
    orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending 
             ? (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderBy(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpr)) 
             : (orderedQuery == null ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpr) : orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpr));
}
```

Then you can call it in each place where you have it copied right now:

```
if (property.Type == typeof(int))
{
    var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda//...etc.
    setQueryOrderingFromSortFilter(sortFilter, sortExpr, orderedQuery);
}
else if (property.Type == typeof(bool))
{
    var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda//..etc.
    setQueryOrderingFromSortFilter(sortFilter, sortExpr, orderedQuery);
}
// etc...
```

**Readability**

Ternary operators are compact but can be difficult to read. Nested ternary operators even more so. You're not saving any time by using them instead of `if`/`else` blocks, but you are hurting readability. Just make a simple set of 2 `if`/`else` blocks for setting the query ordering and be done with it.

Same thing with the `NestedExpressionProperty()` function. That return statement is very confusing. It looks at first glance to be returning a boolean!

Also, it would improve readability if you put some whitespace between your functions.

**Why are you returning a reference parameter?**

Your function signature is this:

```
private static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression property, ParameterExpression sortParam, SortFilter sortFilter, ref IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery)
```

The last parameter, `orderedQuery`, is a reference parameter. So you're actually changing the variable. But then you also return it. That seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.    For the first part I wanted to make that setQueryOrderingFromSortFilter a seperate function but was not sure of the sortExpr type. It is different in each scenario. I am using var in each case but dont know how to mark that as a common type that can be applied on all types. I liked the recommendation of reference parameter, and I removed return type from it as you rightly said it is redundant. And yes from readability point of view ternary operators are little difficult to understand.

Comment: @rednerus Something like `private void SetQueryOrderingFromSortFilter<T>(SortFilter sortFilter, Expression<Func<T, object>> sortExpr, ref IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery)`? Not sure if that's correct, however.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like what @BCdotWEB said. I'm not as familiar with C# syntax as I am with C++, so sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @user1118321's review, I would also suggest to rethink your conditions.

You seem to tend to do "negative" checks, you're even combining two in this case: `if (sortFilter != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilter.SortOn))`. I'd much rather have this logic: `if (sortFilter == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilter.SortOn))`. To me this second version is easier to understand: if the `sortFilter` is null or its `SortOn` is null or empty, then execute this simple bit of code that doesn't need the `sortFilter`, otherwise execute this more complicated bit of code that requires the `sortFilter`.

This is IMHO even more important when using ternary operators. Parsing `orderedQuery = !sortFilter.IsDescending` requires me to think a lot more than if you'd written `orderedQuery = sortFilter.IsDescending`.